# ООП и обращение процедур объекта к его полям в C#

Tags: c#, ооп, моделирование

Пишу небольшую программу для моделирования простой СМО с отказами. В силу своей неопытности наткнулся на проблему чуть ли не с самого начала. Код, который я имею и который не работает:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace mmc
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceSystem mySystem = new ServiceSystem(260, 5, 4, 3);
            mySystem.Init();
        }
    }

    public class ServiceSystem {
    public int RenderTime, // общее время моделирования
    ArrivalTime, // интервал поступления заявок
    ChannelCount, // количество каналов
    QueueCapacity; // размер очереди

    class Channel {
        internal int ProcessTime; // время обработки заявки
        bool isBusy; // занят?
    }

    class Queue {
        internal int Capacity, // размер очереди
        Occupied; // занятых мест
        bool isFull; // заполнена?
    }

    int RequestAll, // всего заявок
    RequestProcessed, // обработано заявок
    RequestRejected; // отклонено заявок

    public ServiceSystem(int _RenderTime, int _ArrivalTime, int _ChannelCount, int _QueueCapacity) {
        RenderTime = _RenderTime;
        ArrivalTime = _ArrivalTime;
        ChannelCount = _ChannelCount;
        QueueCapacity = _QueueCapacity;
    }

    public void Init() {
        List<string>[] Timeline = new List<string>[RenderTime]; // линия времени
        Channel[] ChannelArray = new Channel[ChannelCount]; // массив каналов

        for (int i = 0; i < RenderTime; i++) {
            Timeline[i] = new List<string>();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ChannelCount; i++) {
            ChannelArray[i] = new Channel();
        }

        foreach (Channel ch in ChannelArray) {
            ch.ProcessTime = 3;
        }

        Queue MainQueue = new Queue();
        MainQueue.Capacity = QueueCapacity;

        // заполнить таймлайн посутплениями
    }

    void RequestAdd() {
        //
    }

    void RequestProcess() {
        //
    }

    void RequestReject() {
        //
    }

    public void Model() {
        foreach (List<string> str in Timeline) {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

}

Не компилируется из-за первой строчки функции `Model()` и понятно почему: `Timeline` был объявлен в другой функции `Init()`, но дописать к объявлению `Timeline` `public` я не могу, перенести объявление в объявление самого класса тоже нельзя, потому что тогда выдаётся ошибка "нельзя обращаться к нестатическим полям", но если сделать поля `ServiceSystem` статическими, то перестаёт работать конструктор `ServiceSystem`.

Comment: Так же можно решить проблему добавление возможности get, которая будет просто возвращать значение поля и бросить его как аргуемент функции init

Answer (score 2):

В Вашем коде `List<string>[] Timeline` - локальная переменная в методе `Init`. Сделайте этот массив членом класса.

```
public class ServiceSystem {
  ...

  List<string>[] Timeline;

  public int RenderTime
  {
    get 
    {
      return (Timeline == null)? 0 : Timeline.Length;
    }
    set
    {
      int oldLength = RenderTime;
      if (value == oldLength)
        return;

      List<string>[] old = Timeline;
      Timeline = new List<string>[value];
      for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(oldLength, Timeline.Length); i++)
      {
        Timeline[i] = old[i];
      }
      for (int i = oldLength; i < Timeline.Length; i++)
      {
        Timeline[i] = new List<string>();
      }
    }
  }

  public void Init() {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```